# Sitecore doing random things

Tags: javascript, client, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a feeling that our Sitecore install is messed up with the configuration but I can't point out where. Things happen at random in the Sitecore client. For example -

- Clicks in the Sitecore client do nothing.
- If I log out say after opening up Log Viewer and then log back in, I only see the log viewer and no other options.
- Clicking on a link would log me out.
- If I am logged in and another admin tries to log in with his/her credentials, sometimes they see my credentials.
- IE 8 continuously throws 'scWin' related javascript errors.

The first 4 are consistent across firefox, chrome and IE. The last one is totally an IE occurrence.

An IIS reset fixes these issues but then these occurrences start happening again pretty quickly.

I've looked at log files but I don't see anything there. What else can I do here?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest stable Sitecore release?

Comment: The site is still in development and testing phases so not yet.

Comment: So which Sitecore version you use?

Comment: Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 and DMS 2.0.0 rev.110602

Comment: Nope. The install has been around for over 6 months and the issues started happening this week. Configuration wise, I haven't noticed any changes either when I go to showconfig.aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be .NET caching -  section - was turned on and was causing all sorts of issues. We removed this and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds really strange. Are you sure you are not infected with some kind of malware or some virus?
Does it occur on every pc that is working with this solution?

You could try to remove the Sitecore files and copy fresh files from the install zip to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: It also comes to mind that it might be some wrong or corrupt configuration of Sitecore/IIS/.NET Framework that causes this strange behavior. It might be even better to start out with a complete new and fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound rather strange... First thing I would do is make sure you followed the IE setup guide exactly, to make sure it's not your browser causing problem.  Javascript is definitely enabled, yes?  The fact that it happens in Firefox also though means this probably isn't the real issue.  Martijn might be on to something... have you tried using another machine entirely to access the site?